# How to run selected Azkaban jobs in paralell via a script?

Tags: hadoop, azkaban

Since there are too many jobs on `Azkaban`, I have to test new jobs **one by one** manually.

Assume I upload some new jobs and is it possible to write a `Python` (or any other language) script to fetch the dependencies between these jobs and then run them on `Azkaban` **in paralell**?

For instance, there are there jobs `a, b, c` and `b` dependents on `a`. They are supposed to be scheduled like:

1. Starts to run job `a` **and** job `c`
2. When job a finishes, starts to run job b.

I did not find any helpful info or API on the `Azkaban` official website (Maybe I missed useful info).

Any help is appreciated.